# Is there a tool to help quickly define animation frames from non-uniform size sprite sheets?

Tags: animation, spritesheet

Many of the sprite sheets online have non-uniform sized rectangles as the animation frames and often use a portion of the image for credits, etc., this makes it hard for a game engine to correctly clip the sheets.

Is there any tool that can help you quickly define frames in a sheet, export animation data which the game engine would use?

Comment: Wow, I was thinking about asking this -exact- question about two weeks ago.

Comment: There is a [sprite sheet packer](http://spritesheetpacker.codeplex.com/), but it generates spritesheets from raw frames.

Comment: @Dan7: If these tools help achieve what you want and therefore answer your question, you should post the links to these tools (and maybe a short description how you solved your problem) as an answer. They don't really belong to the question, unless you want to list them as "unusable" solutions to your problem.

Comment: They are not exactly what I wanted though, they have their own "catch" when it comes to the approaches. But you are right I should move them to an answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm the creator of darkFunction Editor. It does exactly what you asked for (in fact specialises in animating non-uniform sprite sheets). Check out the Beta, it's very stable now. What are the 'catches' you are referring to? If there is anything missing please let me know and I can try to include it in the next release! :)

Comment: @Sam Hi, darkFunction Editor is very stable and responsive compared to Sprite Vortex, and a bit more powerful too (I like the combiner feature!). Although a couple of things I miss is the auto-detection with one button when defining frames, and the ability to drag a list item on the tree view. In animation editor, it would be great if by clicking "add to frame", it can add to a new animation cell by default, without the need to create and select the cell first. Anyhow it's a great tool, thanks for the hard work!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll definitely be implementing the first two suggestions-- the draggable tree stuff was already next on the Todo list :) As for add to frame, well, you might need more than one sprite per frame which is the main advantage darkFunction has over the other editors, the ability to have many sprites in each frame. I will be adding an example to the next release but it is perfect for complex sheets like this one: http://www.spriters-resource.com/arcade/gradiusgaiden/sheet/40680

Comment: Ah I see, that's very good thinking! I've never thought about this use before, and this opens up a lot more possiblities. Keep up the great work :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Moved from question body]* Here's a list of what I've found by googling:

- **[Sprite Vortex](https://github.com/rafaelvasco/SpriteVortex)** : It can auto-detect frames. There has been some crashes and is still buggy, otherwise it's a very good option. When you are exporting, make sure you click the root item instead of individual animation in the tree view to export all animation definitions.
- **darkFunction Editor** (http://darkfunction.com/): By double-clicking a sprite, it will automatically make a frame. Still some manual work but works great so far.
- **[Spritimator](https://www.google.com/search?q=spritimator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t)**: Saw this used by a tutorial, but the author's webpage seems down at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

Usually such sprite sheets come with an additional file with coordinates for the packed frames (some might even be rotated). Extracting frames without these coordinates can really be a cumbersome task. Automating it would also be very hard to do, since a single sprite doesn't necessarily have a contiguous shape.

If the coordinates file is missing, I'd probably use the [Photoshop Slice tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Photoshop/11.0/WSE311D2B1-CA39-4bab-8BEE-25CF899D1486a.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-756ba) to mark individual frames and then you can export all slices at once by using "Save for Web & Devices".